# WCF .net Framework 4.0 to WCF .net Framework 4.6.1 Failed to work

Tags: c#, wcf

Hello when migrating my WCF project from .net framework 4.0 to .net framework 4.6.1, the client authentication became faulted. [Here is the image of the error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jGGcb.png) What to do? thanks..

Comment: Is it a self-hosted WCF-Service or an IIS-Solution? Which Authentication are you using and do you impersonate or not?

Comment: I am using self-hosted WCF-Service with message security via net.tcp. the client is working on .net framework 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just fixed the Issue by adding

```
<runtime>
   <AppContextSwitchOverrides value="Switch.System.IdentityModel.DisableMultipleDNSEntriesInSANCertificate=true" /> 
</runtime>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt620030(v=vs.110).aspx